# How often will a function be called in a ternary operator?

Tags: java

I have this line of Java code:

```
return getValue() != null ? getValue() : 0
```

How often will `getValue` be executed? Once or twice?

**EDIT:** If this is compiler-dependant, I'm especially interested in the compiler from the Sun JDK.

Comment: Off topic: auto-boxing is evil, prefer explicit `valueOf(0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if getValue() == null - once

if getValue() != null - twice

Comment: Of course the runtime bytecode -> machine code compiler (typically HotSpot), may inline it and do common subexpression elimination (CSE).

Comment: Actually it cannot inline it, since it might have side effects, and compiler can't know that.

Comment: The JIT-compiler COULD know if the method has side effects. The questions is just how much time it spends (if any at all) to test that.

Comment: No, it can't know, at least not in language like Java. You would have to mark each method in each class as side-effect free or not in order for JIT to figure it out. And bytecode doesn't have such info.

Comment: Sorry but that is wrong. Though I don't know if the sun VM does this I have seen several JIT compilers that do this. And finding out if you method has side effects or not does not need any special bytecode support. As an example: if the implementation of getValue() is return null; then it is trivial to decide that there are no side effects. In fact in that case the compiler would optimize out the entire if-construct.

Comment: I have to append that the JIT compilers were compliant Java JITs.

Comment: And this is the reason I'd want an Elvis operator. Because putting it in a lambda in a stream 'filter' for example requires less code / calls.

Answer (score 3):

only once if getValue() returns null, twice if the first time returned something other than null.

Answer (score 2):

Cleared answer:

**From a developer perspective:**

if getValue() == null - Will be called once

if getValue() != null - Will be called twice

**From the JIT-Compiler perspective:**

Depends on the compiler and your method. It will be at most called 2 times and at least 0 times.

- Two times if not null; the compiler doesn't optimize; or the method has side effects
- Zero times if first call to getValue() ALWAYS return null and has no side effects and the compiler does that optimization

Answer (score 2):

If `getValue()` returns a non-null value, twice.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    boolean x = t.doSomething()? t.doSomething():false;
}
public boolean doSomething(){
    System.out.println("calling doSomething");
    return true;
}
}
```

output:

```
calling doSomething
calling doSomething
```

Comment: This is probably a bad test. I don't think this can be optimized away at all. If you just had `return true;`, it might be optimized into one call.

Comment: I you do "return true" the whole expression might be replaced by "true", so it won't be called at all.

Answer (score 2):

Could you re-write it? I'm not familiar with Java, but in C++ you could say

```
return (x=getvalue()) != null ? x : 0
```

And if that wouldn't work in Java, could you move the assignment before the return? Does it need to be a single line?

```
x = getvalue();
return x != null ? x : 0
```

John C>

Answer (score 0):

I have a different scenario that is related to your question. I also want to set a value to a variable that is a result of the ternary operator like this:

```
String thing = something == null ? "the other thing" : getSomethingElse();
```

That code **still executes** "getSomethingElse()" even if "something" **is** null.

It seems that all the functions within a ternary operator get executed before the evaluation of the condition---contrary to answers given by others.